# How do I programmatically put line breaks into a textarea

Tags: html

I am using a textarea field to display the status of a form submission. The form itself allows the user to delete one or more images.

Currently the textarea is showing:
**1234.pdf has been deleted. 5678.pdf has been deleted.** (no line-breaks)

I'd like it to look like:
**1234.pdf has been deleted.

5678.pdf has been deleted.**

I've tried putting in `<br/>` (which then shows the `<br/>` in the text, but doesn't cause a line break) and I've tried Environment.NewLine, which seems to get ignored and ends up showing the first example above.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Programmatically... in what language?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both:

```
<textarea rows="10" cols="30">
1234.pdf has been deleted.
5678.pdf has been deleted.
</textarea>
```

and

```
<textarea rows="10" cols="30">
1234.pdf has been deleted.&#10;5678.pdf has been deleted.
</textarea>
```

should work. So if you write output from PHP for example just put \n or `&#10;` at the end of every string and will work. If you use C# or vb.net use (char)10 for C# or chr(10) for .vb.

[Fiddler](http://jsfiddle.net/ZeroWorks/YHN27/)

Answer (score 3):

Use line feed and carriage return characters

```
line 1 &#13;&#10; line 2
```

the `&#13;&#10;` should make a line break

Proof this works: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pW2hN/)

Answer (score 1):

Try using &#10

```
<textarea rows="10" cols="30">
  I'm playing &#10 in the garden.
</textarea>
```

Comment: You forgot the ";" I think